# How do I configure NetFlow 5/9 export on Juniper switches?

Tags: monitoring, switch, bandwidth, juniper, netflow

What are the commands to make a Juniper switch send netflow data (V5 or V9) to a netflow collector for bandwidth monitoring?

Answer (score 3):

I presume by switch you mean the EX2/3/4000 range, in which case, it is not supported.

sflow is supported if that's what you would like, though it's not implemented on the version we use. I heard it was to be implemented on 9.5R.

There is a "hack" you can do by mirroring a port and then running something like pmacct or ntop on it, then generating Netflow records from the mirrored data, but this isn't a sustainable scenario.

The EX8200 series will support sflow and Netflow (with a cflowd export line similar to other Juniper products).

Comment: 5 years on, someone has brought up this post with me and told me that the EX8200 most certainly does NOT support cflow. It's sufficiently long ago that I can't remember why I wrote the above. Hopefully anyone reading this in the future will then be suitably informed!